# Dynamic Web API Controller not created

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

i'm trying to add new IApplicationService on existing web application but ABP doesn't register that

here is my code

interface

```
    public interface iElementAppService:  IApplicationService
    {
        Task<long> CountElementsAsync();
    }
```

implementation

```
public class GretaAppService : BBWP_ABP_MPA_EFAppServiceBase, iElementAppService
    {
        public Task<long> CountElementsAsync()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public GretaAppService()
        {

        }
```

all my other Dynamic web api controller is created except this one

Comment: does BBWP_ABP_MPA_EFAppServiceBase inherits ApplicationService?

Comment: just a long shot, did you tried, renaming your Interface and Concrete class the same name, public class ElementAppService

Comment: yes @MauhammadKamranAslam iI have already tried to rename the class.
 BBWP_ABP_MPA_EFAppServiceBase inherits ApplicationService

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved by capitalizing the letters i of the iElementAppService interface to IElementAppService  :(